# Validate a textbox using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have  TextBox and a Button

first the button is in disabled position
 When the user starts typing the text in textbox
     the button should be enabled

How can i achieve this using JQuery or Java Script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with this also

```
 <input type='text' id='textbox'>
    <input type="button" class="button-disabled" id="change" disabled="disabled" value="click">


    $("#textbox").keyup(checkForm).focus(checkForm);
    function checkForm()
    {
        if($("#textbox").val()=='')
           {
          $("#change").addClass("button-disabled").removeClass("button");
          $("#change").attr("disabled","disabled");
           }
           else
            {
           $("#change").removeClass("button-disabled").addClass("button");
           $("#change").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you are a newbie to jQuery. I would say you start with [jQuery Tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) and then move on to [jQuery Validate](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/). If you prefer books to start with, you can pick up a copy of [jQuery in Action](http://www.manning.com/bibeault/).

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type='text' id='textbox'>
<input type="button" id="button'" value="click me"> 

$('#button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$('#textbox').change(function(){$('#button').removeAttr('disabled')} );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="myText">
<input type="submit" id="myButton" disabled="disable"/>


jQuery(function(){

jQuery('#myText').bind('keypress',function(e){
    if((jQuery(e.target).val()+"").length>0)
    {
       jQuery('#myButton').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else
    {
       jQuery('#myButton').attr('disabled','disable');
    }
});

});
```

Comment: The `if((jQuery(e.target).val()+"").length>0)` could be simplified to `if( this.value.length > 0 )` considering this will run on every keypress on the text input

Comment: I HAVE TO DO WITH ASP COTROLS

Comment: use clientID of control or add css class to the control and replace this "jQuery('#myText')" with "jQuery('.your_css_class_name')"

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='textbox'>
<input type="button" id="mybutton" value="click me">
```

JS:

```
$(document).load(function() {
    $('#mybutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}

$('#textbox').change(function() {
    $('#mybutton').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Update: regarding the use of jQuery w/ ASP.NET, keep in mind that ASP.NET outputs standard HTML once the page is rendered, so the above code would work similarly, except you need to figure out the ID's of the textboxes generated by ASP.net.  See this link for further explanation on this:
http://www.search-this.com/2009/08/06/using-jquery-with-asp-net-controls/

Comment: I think this works for HTML controls,but i have asp.net controls

Comment: I updated my post to elaborate on the use of jquery w/ asp.net. hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='text' id='thetext' value=''>
<input type='button' disabled='disabled' id='thebutton' value='the button'>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#thetext').change(function(){
      $('#thebutton').removeAttr('disabled');
   });
});
```

Read up on the jQuery API : http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: I WANT TO DO WITH ASP CONTROLS